# nesting sql statements and selecting (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, metadata, nested

Given the following MySQL-statement:

```
SELECT table_name,column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
AND column_name REGEXP 'ID$'
ORDER BY table_name,ordinal_position
```

I would like to select from the result all columns that contain a certain ID #.

Since I don't know the exact name of the column or table I should apply my 2nd SELECT, I need to apply my SELECT to some kind of "placeholders", I think.

E.g., if the resultset of the first request is:

```
('wp_links', 'link_id')
('wp_options', 'option_id')
('wp_postmeta', 'meta_id')
('wp_postmeta', 'post_id')
```

then the select should comprise all table_name that are in the first column of the result and should take the column_name of the second column of the result as argument to test whether it contains a certain ID #.

In other words I would like to find all columns in a certain database that are named *_ID and contain a certain ID# and know their corresponding table_name the column belongs to.

Comment: Can you edit the question with sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're wanting to in SQL but you could do it using procedural SQL, either in a procedure or an anonymous block.

Create a cursor which loops through the results of your statement above. When looping through the results, construct the string you want to execute on each table to see if the desired id exists and execute the query. You will create this string by doing something like:

```
SET sql_statament = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", v_table_name," WHERE ", v_column_name," = ", v_id_number);
```

This tutorial should help: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Answer (score 0):

You want to do two different things:

1. Get information on your database (table and column names).
2. Get data from your database (values from columns).

You cannot do both at the same time. You can use some programming language firing first an SQL query to get table names and columns and then build a query or several queries to get the data.